# python SIP log file processing

Tags: python, logging, text

i have a sniff/log file for VoIP/SIP generated by python scapy in format
time | src | srcport | dst | dstport | payload
the sniff python script looks like this:

```
## Import Scapy module
from scapy.all import *
import sys

sys.stdout = open('data.txt', 'w')

pkts = sniff(filter="udp and port 5060 and not port 22", count=0,prn=lambda x:x.sprintf("%sent.time% | %IP.src% | %IP.sport% | %IP.dst% | %IP.dport% | Payload {Raw:%Raw.load%\n}"))
```

each packet in one line and each line can have different size depends on SIP message type (Register, 200 OK, Invite, Notify and so on...)

What i would like to get from the file are fields
`time, src, srcport, dst, dstport` and from `Payload` type (just right after Payload) of `SIP message, From, To, Call-iD, Contact`
and the whole payload and then prepare these to insert into MySQL database.

```
1st msg:
07:57:01.894990 | 192.168.1.10 | 5060 | 192.168.1.1 | 5060 | Payload 'INVITE sip:210@test-lab.org SIP/2.0\r\nVia: 
SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.10:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bK-9cbb0ba8\r\nRoute: <sip:192.168.1.1:5060;lr>\r\nFrom: "test-311" <sip:311@test-lab.org>;tag=3d13bd6f\r\n
To: <sip:210@test-lab.org>\r\nCall-ID: 21b0e2c755973976d6d06702ca33b32f@10.193.40.249\r\nCSeq: 1 INVITE\r\n
Contact: "test-311" <sip:311@192.168.1.10:5060;transport=UDP>\r\nMax-Forwards: 70\r\n
Supported: 100rel,replaces\r\nAllow: ACK, BYE, CANCEL, INFO, INVITE, OPTIONS, NOTIFY, PRACK, REFER, UPDATE, MESSAGE\r\nContent-Type: application/sdp\r\nContent-Length:   276\r\n\r\nv=0\r\no=- 3506863524 285638052 IN IP4 192.168.1.10\r\ns=-\r\nc=IN IP4 192.168.1.10\r\nt=0 0\r\nm=audio 8000 RTP/AVP 8 0 18 101\r\nc=IN IP4 192.168.1.10\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:18 G729/8000\r\na=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000\r\na=fmtp:101 0-15\r\na=ptime:20\r\n'

2nd msg:
07:57:01.902618 | 192.168.1.1 | 5060 | 192.168.1.10 | 5060 | Payload 'SIP/2.0 100 Trying\r\nVia: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.10:5060;received=192.168.1.10;branch=z9hG4bK-9cbb0ba8;rport=5060\r\nFrom: "test-311" <sip:+38551311@test-lab.org>;tag=3d13bd6f\r\nTo: <sip:210@test-lab.org>\r\nCall-ID: 21b0e2c755973976d6d06702ca33b32f@192.168.1.10\r\nCSeq: 1 INVITE\r\n\r\n'
```

I have tried to read line by line and split but I do not know how to split and take data from payload part.
Any help is more then welcome.

Comment: Have you looked at the `csv` module? https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can enter the data into mysql straight from this program too; it might very well be the easiest approach.

```
from scapy.all import *
import sys

# connect to mysql 
connection = ...

def insert_into_mysql(packet):
    # now you can use packet.src, packet.sport, packet.dst, packet.dport, and
    # I believe packet['Raw'].load
    connection.execute(...)

    # to not print the packet
    return None

    # to print the packet
    return x.sprintf("%sent.time% | %IP.src% | %IP.sport% | %IP.dst% | %IP.dport% | Payload {Raw:%Raw.load%\n}"

pkts = sniff(filter="udp and port 5060", count=0, store=0, prn=insert_into_mysql)
```

But if you need to use the existing log, I think you need to use:

```
for line in open('log.txt'):
    sent_time, src, sport, dst, dport, payload = line.split(' | ', 6)
    payload = payload.replace('Payload ', '')

    # to get the unquoted payload, I'd guess (can't test SIP though)
    from ast import literal_eval
    payload = literal_eval(payload)
```

Comment: i decided to go with first option and insert directly into DB but does not work. I guess i did something wrong in script

Comment: then make a new question

Answer (score 0):

from scapy.all import *
import MySQLdb, string, sys

def insert_into_mysql(packet):
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","test","testpwd","my_db" )

```
cursor = db.cursor()
# now you can use packet.src, packet.sport, packet.dst, packet.dport, 
# and packet['Raw'].load
add_sip = ("INSERT INTO py_sniff "
            "(time, src_ip, src_port, dst_ip, dst_port, message) "
            "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")

# data from sniff
add_sip = {
    'time': packet.sprintf("%sent.time%"),
    'src_ip': packet.sprintf("%IP.src%"),
    'src_port': packet.sprintf("%IP.sport%"),
    'dst_ip': packet.sprintf("%IP.dst%"),
    'dst_port': packet.sprintf("%IP.dport%"),
    'message': packet.sprintf("{Raw:%Raw.load%}"),
}

# to print the packet
# return packet.sprintf("%sent.time% | %IP.src% | %IP.sport% | %IP.dst% | %IP.dport% | Payload {Raw:%Raw.load%\n}"

cursor.execute(add_sip)
db.commit()
```

pkts = sniff(iface="eth0", filter="udp and port 5060", count=0, store=0, prn=insert_into_mysql)